# Цикл for в конструкторе класса

Tags: kotlin

Пытаюсь изучать котлин и вот скажем есть конструктор класса :

```
// Конструктор
public class TESTCLSS constructor()
{
    for (i in 1..20)
    {
        print(i);
    }
}
```

сразу же получаю ошибку,
на цикл :

```
Function declaration must have a name
```

и на i

```
Unresolved reference: i
```

Как с этим справиться?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В коде из вопроса вы создаете класс, и сразу в самом классе (не в конструкторе) вставляете цикл. Конструктор класса в данном случае - это `constructor()` и все. Ниже в фигурных скобках уже идет тело класса.

> Первичный конструктор является частью заголовка класса, его объявление идёт сразу после имени класса (и необязательных параметров)
>
> ...
>
> Первичный конструктор не может содержать в себе исполняемого кода. Инициализирующий код может быть помещён в соответствующий блок (**initializers blocks**), который помечается словом **init**

См. [Классы и наследование](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/classes.html).

Исполняемый код (цикл в данном случае) должен быть в инициализаторе или в методе класса (в том числе во вторичном конструкторе, например) или в отдельной функции вне класса.

Рабочий пример с циклом в отдельной функции:

```
fun prn() {
    for (i in 1..20)
    {
        print(i.toString() + " ");
    }
}

fun main() {
    prn()
}
```

Пример с вызовом метода класса (пустой первичный конструктор может явно не прописываться):

```
public class TESTCLSS
{
    fun prn() {
        for (i in 1..20)
        {
            print(i.toString() + " ");
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    TESTCLSS().prn()
}
```

Выполнение кода в инициализаторе первичного конструктора:

```
public class TESTCLSS
{
    init {
        for (i in 1..20)
        {
            print(i.toString() + " ");
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    TESTCLSS()
}
```

Выполнение кода во вторичном конструкторе:

```
public class TESTCLSS
{
    constructor()  {
        for (i in 1..20)
        {
            print(i.toString() + " ");
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    TESTCLSS()
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Иногда, когда я смотрю на kotlin код - хочется убить автора языка... :)

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar, дело вкуса и привычки. Меня вот бесит то как в Go типы указываются) А kotlin в принципе нормально, в чем-то похож на привычный мне Python, в чем-то на Java, но намного менее многословный чем Java. Определение класса непривычное, но довольно компактное, и удобное, если разобраться)